# How to compute the inverse of a polynomial under GF(2^8)?

Tags: polynomials, inverse

It's well known that AES cryptography algorithm uses 
Galois Field GF(2^8) multiplication to process the step 
MixColumn, and each column of the 4*4 matrix on encrypting
should multiply the polynomial 3X^3 + X^2 + X + 2 which 
is usually notated as an array {0x03, 0x01, 0x01, 0x02}, 
while on decrypting, the matrix should multiply the inverse 
of the polynominal mentioned above, namely 0x0B*X^3 + 
0x0D*X^2 + 0x09*X + 0x0E which can also notated as 
an array {0x0B, 0x0D, 0x09, 0x0E}.

Now I wonder If only one polynomial is known, e.g. {0x03, 0x01, 0x01, 0x02}, 
how can I compute its inverse mod (X^4 + 1), namely 
{0x0B, 0x0D, 0x09, 0x0E}, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

The usual method is to apply [the extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to your polynomial $p(x)$ and $x^4+1=(x+1)^4$.

Observe that $$p(1)=0\text{x}03\operatorname{XOR} 0\text{x}01 \operatorname{XOR} 0\text{x}01 \operatorname{XOR} 0\text{x}02=0\text{x}01=1\neq0,$$ so we know that there are no common factors. Therefore the extended Euclidean algorithm will produce polynomials
$u(x)$ and $v(x)$ with coefficients in $GF(2^8)$ such that
$$
u(x)p(x)+v(x)(x^4+1)=1.
$$
And from this you can read that the polynomial $u(x)$ (you can reduce it modulo $x^4+1$ to get a unique result) is the inverse you are looking for.

Comment: Dear Sir, Would you please elaborate it with an example, as I got confused at some steps?